# Determine primitive types using roslyn

Tags: c#, types, roslyn

Using Roslyn, how to determine whether an `ITypeSymbol` is a primitive type or not?

The `ITypeSymbol` does not have the `IsPrimitive` property like `Type.IsPrimitive`

Is there a way to convert `ITypeSymbol` to Type or some other way to determine whether an `ITypeSymbol` is a primitive type?

Comment: http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers/Shared/Extensions/ITypeSymbolExtensions.cs,99dedadc48293f12

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: To have extension methods?

Comment: It contains extension methods for `ITypeSymbol`, so its name starts with `ITypeSymbol`.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the code to determine that is in the [TypedConstant class](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/TypedConstant.cs,5aa4528d694ad774,references), but it is internal and I couldn't find a public API that would nicely get me there. I ended up copying the method into to my project.

```
    /// <remarks>
    /// TypedConstant isn't computing its own kind from the type symbol because it doesn't
    /// have a way to recognize the well-known type System.Type.
    /// </remarks>
    internal static TypedConstantKind GetTypedConstantKind(ITypeSymbol type, Compilation compilation)
    {
        Debug.Assert(type != null);

        switch (type.SpecialType)
        {
            case SpecialType.System_Boolean:
            case SpecialType.System_SByte:
            case SpecialType.System_Int16:
            case SpecialType.System_Int32:
            case SpecialType.System_Int64:
            case SpecialType.System_Byte:
            case SpecialType.System_UInt16:
            case SpecialType.System_UInt32:
            case SpecialType.System_UInt64:
            case SpecialType.System_Single:
            case SpecialType.System_Double:
            case SpecialType.System_Char:
            case SpecialType.System_String:
            case SpecialType.System_Object:
                return TypedConstantKind.Primitive;
            default:
                switch (type.TypeKind)
                {
                    case TypeKind.Array:
                        return TypedConstantKind.Array;
                    case TypeKind.Enum:
                        return TypedConstantKind.Enum;
                    case TypeKind.Error:
                        return TypedConstantKind.Error;
                }

                if (compilation != null &&
                    compilation.IsSystemTypeReference(type))
                {
                    return TypedConstantKind.Type;
                }

                return TypedConstantKind.Error;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether a type is primitive or not depends on your language. In C# DateTime is not a primitive, but it is in VB. Since ITypeSymbol is used for both languages, it does not have language-specific properties.

Comment: DateTime is not a primitive type in VB. If you look at [Type.IsPrimitive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), there is exact language-agnostic description there:

`The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following extension methods:

```
    //eg: symbol.IsFullNameEquals("List`1", "Generic", "Collections", "System")
    internal static bool IsFullNameEquals(this ISymbol symbol, params string[] nameParts) {
        if (symbol == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("symbol");
        if (nameParts == null || nameParts.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("nameParts");
        var idx = 0;
        for (; symbol != null; symbol = symbol.ContainingSymbol) {
            var name = symbol.MetadataName;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) break;
            if (idx == nameParts.Length) return false;
            if (name != nameParts[idx]) return false;
            idx++;
        }
        return idx == nameParts.Length;
    }

    //eg: var idx = symbol.MatchFullName(new []{"List`1", "Dictionary`2"}, new []{"Generic", "Collections", "System"});
    //return value: -1: none; 0: symbol is List`1; 1: symbol is Dictionary`2 
    internal static int MatchFullName(this ISymbol symbol, string[] typeNames, string[] outerNameParts) {
        if (symbol == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("symbol");
        if (typeNames == null || typeNames.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentNullException("typeNames");
        var fullLength = 1 + (outerNameParts != null ? outerNameParts.Length : 0);
        int idx = 0, result = -1;
        for (; symbol != null; symbol = symbol.ContainingSymbol) {
            var name = symbol.MetadataName;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) break;
            if (idx == fullLength) return -1;
            if (idx == 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < typeNames.Length; i++) {
                    if (name == typeNames[i]) {
                        result = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (result == -1) return -1;
            }
            else {
                if (name != outerNameParts[idx - 1]) return -1;
            }
            idx++;
        }
        if (idx == fullLength) return result;
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Why not just call compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName() and just use .Equals() to compare the instances? Much easier and less fiddly.

Comment: @Jason Malinowski `var idx = symbol.MatchFullName(new []{"Type1", "Type2", ... "TypeN"}, new []{"NS2", "NS1"});` is much easier than multiple GetTypeByMetadataName() and Equals()